# Merging multiple csvs the right way in panda

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have been trying to work out how to combine several (variable amount of) csvs that all contain one same column and column data in Python. I have been looking at panda and have had only a limited success using merge, join or concat. My closest attempt was with concat (see code below). This brought together all the data but added the common field each time.

So I would have for example:

csv1

| Food | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit |
| Brocolli | Veg |
| Milk | Drink |

csv2

| Food | Location |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | UK |
| Brocolli | Spain |
| Milk | US |

Desired result csv:

| Food | Type | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit | UK |
| Brocolli | Veg | Spain |
| Milk | Drink | US |

Current result (with code below):

| Food | Type | Food | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Fruit | Apple | UK |
| Brocolli | Veg | Brocolli | Spain |
| Milk | Drink | Milk | US |

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance

````
import glob
import pandas as pd
curdir = os.getcwd()
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(curdir, "*37604.csv"))
df_from_each_file = (pd.read_csv(csvfiles) for csvfiles in all_files)
df_merged   = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, axis=1, ignore_index=False)
df_merged.to_csv("merged_37604.csv", index=False)```
````

Comment: `df_merged.drop(['Food'], axis=1).to_csv(..`

Comment: `concat` only works if you have exactly same number of foods in exactly same order.  If you want to merge the Location to Type based on the same food, try `df1.merge(df2, on='Food')`.  If you use merge on "Food", it won't add extra "Food" column.  Add `how` option if necessary.  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: Thanks the df_merged.drop line works in that it appends all the fields I need without the food column reappearing but it does get rid of the food column altogether. There are about 6 columns in total. Apologies I'm a bit new to panda. There are going to be exactly the same number of rows for each and all in the same order